# How to convert pseudo code to Python 2.x?

Tags: python

Here is the pseudo-code for an Over Produced Management System:

```
Add memory library module

Prompt; 1)search for item, 2)add over produced item

If search for item
Prompt input item number

    If item number in database print available quantity

    Else print “None available”

Else if add over produced item
Prompt input item number
    If item number in database
    Prompt “how many”
    Add quantity to inventory
    Else if item number not in inventory
    Add item to inventory with quantity
```

Comment: I smell homework

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
db = {}
while True:
    if raw_input("Prompt; 1)search for item, 2)add over produced item > ") == "1":
        item = raw_input("Item number? > ")
        if item in db:
            print("Available: " + str(db[item]))
        else:
            print("None available")
    else:
        item = raw_input("Item number? > ")
        qty = int(raw_input("Quantity? > "))
        if item in db:
            db[item] += qty
        else:
            db[item] = qty
```

Comment: you shouldn't answer if the OP hasn't shown any effort from their end :)

Comment: My bad, I tested it before posting, but I somehow screwed up the indentation when pasteing it in. It has been fixed.

Comment: Something with pickle please